# How can I remove button I press in Flex?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

When I try this it doesn't remove the right button. Could you please point me in the right direction in finding what's wrong.

```
private var myArray:Array = [];
private var myButton:Button;
public function addButton():void {
var i:uint = myArray.length;
                myButton = new Button();
                myButton.label = "New Button"+ String(i);
                myButton.id= "myButton" + String(i);
                myGroup.addElement(myButton);
                myArray.push(myGroup.addElement(myButton));
                myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeButton);
            }
public function removeButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
//myGroup.removeElement(myArray.splice(2,1)); don´t work
//myGroup.removeElement(myArray.pop()); remove the last one
}
```

Comment: So what happens, what do you want to happen, and what have you tried to fix it? Please provide some details

Comment: Thank you for your response, I´m trying to remove the button i click, Example: i add 3 buttons - b1,b2and b3. if i use array.pop and press b1 , the b3 (last) is removed . this is not what i want, i want to remove b1. Hope make sense...

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000744.html says `Removes the last element from an array and returns the value of that element.`. Any surprises that you remove the last button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following. It will work and remove the button which is pressed.

```
public function removeButton(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    myGroup.removeElementAt(myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget));
    myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget), 1); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, work well but the last button get error Index-1 is out if range. i will try go from here.

Comment: I made it. here i am not getting error. There is some problem of index. debug and check.

Comment: something wrong with my component .. if i trace the array myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget), 1); get the right position of the button -perfect. but when i use the other line myGroup.removeElementAt(myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget)); get this error RangeError: Index -1 is out of range.
 at spark.components: . thank you. Don´t now for now what is happen, i let you now.

Comment: thank you one more time work well. The problem was, i have the add button inside the Hgroup. No works very well.

Comment: Use both line in same order as i write in answer. 
 myGroup.removeElementAt(myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget)); is first line and myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget), 1); is second.

Comment: Yes, Ketan work very well. Thank you . No I add the button as a component (comp.*). Start make some debug ... Hope the array find the event.